# Rabbitmq consumer shutting down repeatedly

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have configured a Dead Letter exchange with exponential back off policy. After making these changes, I have started getting an exception in the rabbitmq consumer getting shutdown repeatedly throwing the following exception:

```
Received shutdown signal for consumer tag=amq.ctag--Qn9jFNOd3vxhaHvEw8Nrw
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:715)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:705)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:563)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:532)
```

Can someone please give me some pointers regarding possible causes for this exception?

Thanks,

Shuchi

Comment: Looks like connection closed by Broker...

Comment: Please show all of your Spring configuration; as well as your rabbitmq configuration (DLX/DLQ etc). As Artem said, this means the server closed the connection. Usually, if the server closes the connection there should be something in its log.

Comment: Take a look at the heart beat. And make sure you not blocking the Client from receiving hearbeat frames

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed your queue declarations in spring then make sure any queues that existed in Rabbit before the change have been deleted. RabbitMQ doesn't like it when you try to generate a queue with the same name with different parameters.